# php mail() and same time save data to MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, email

Hi please a little hand here i cant find my error.
When a user click send i need that mail to be sended and also the data to be stored in "users" table. Now the mail works i get the mail, but data is not saved in DB? Why? I know my code needs lots of work since its not optimized.

if i run this in mysql database it works fine:

INSERT INTO uporabniki(IME,PRIIMEK,TELEFON,IZOBRAZBA,EMAIL,OKP,OPS,ODS) VALUES ('rr','dd','123','sad','rr@ee.com','1','2','3')

```
<?php
   include("config.php");
   session_start();


$update_ime=$_POST['ime'];
$update_priimek=$_POST['priimek'];
$update_email=$_POST['email'];
$update_telefon=$_POST['telefon'];
$update_izobrazba=$_POST['izobrazba'];
$update_kraj=$_POST['kraj'];

$update_okp=$_POST['prijava_okp'];
$update_ops=$_POST['prijava_ops'];
$update_ods=$_POST['prijava_ods'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO uporabniki(IME,PRIIMEK,TELEFON,IZOBRAZBA,EMAIL,OKP,OPS,ODS)
VALUES ('$update_ime','$update_priimek','$update_telefon','$update_izobrazba','$update_email','$update_okp','$update_ops','$update_ods')";


$result1 = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT DATUM, HOUR FROM razpisani_tecaji WHERE ID_TECAJA = '$update_okp'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
$date1 = $row['DATUM']; 
    $hour1 = $row['HOUR']; 
}

$result2 = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT DATUM, HOUR FROM razpisani_tecaji WHERE ID_TECAJA = '$update_ops'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
$date2 = $row['DATUM']; 
    $hour2 = $row['HOUR']; 
}

$result3 = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT DATUM, HOUR FROM razpisani_tecaji WHERE ID_TECAJA = '$update_ods'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)){
$date3 = $row['DATUM']; 
    $hour3 = $row['HOUR']; 
}


$to      = 'info@viverius-education.com,rok.ivartnik@viverius.com';
$subject = 'Prijava na tečaj';
$headers = "From: {$update_email} <{$update_email}>\r\n";
$message  = "--------------------------------------------------- \r\n";
$message  .= "Prijavljam se na tečaje: \r\n";
$message  .= "--------------------------------------------------- \r\n";
$message  .= "Online klinični primeri: " . $date1 ." " .$hour1. "\r\n";
$message  .= "Online priprave na strokovni izpit: " . $date2 ." " .$hour2. "\r\n";
$message  .= "Online delavnice za študente medicine: " . $date3 ." " .$hour3. "\r\n";
$message  .= "--------------------------------------------------- \r\n";
$message  .= "Podatki o udeležencu: \r\n";
$message  .= "Ime: " . $update_ime . "\r\n";
$message  .= "Priimek: " . $update_priimek . "\r\n";
$message  .= "Email: " . $update_email . "\r\n";
$message  .= "Telefon: " . $update_telefon . "\r\n";
$message  .= "Status/izobrazba: " . $update_izobrazba . "\r\n";
$message  .= "Ime ustanove/kraja: " . $update_kraj . "\r\n";
$message  .= "--------------------------------------------------- \r\n";


if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
 header('Location: email_uspesno_poslan.html'); exit;
}else{
 header('Location: email_neuspesno_poslan.html'); exit;
}

?>
```

Comment: You should learn to use prepared statements to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Hi @Barmar, will give it a look thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never executed the sql query. Use on of the methods to execute it e.g.

```
$db->query($sql)
```

Or using mysqli

```
mysqli_query($db, $sql)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say. Just assigning a sql statement to a variable isn't enough, you have to execute it somewhere.